# Uncrowd Server Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I want to create a server-client type of program, in which the client and the server send 3 different messages to eachother, and then close the connection. I use threads to start new "ServerWorkers", and these are ones that have a while loop inside of them, that attempt to read the message sent by the client.

What happens if there is someone that tries to attack my server, and open thousands of connections with my server, and they don't send the server any message, so the ServerWorker thread just stays on?

How can I stop these connections? Can I set a timeout for the threads to stop them if a certain time has been surpassed?

Code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes with threads (to close streams that are waiting for too long). Hard to do with your posted code. Also, you would be better off relying on an existing framework. ReST is quite popular (as a protocol). Next, you might have a load balancer between your clients and your actual server. And you might have a firewall between your clients and your load balancer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Have you first created a server and client that does what you want *without* threading? It will make this easier if you do this a small bit at a time.

Comment: @NomadMaker Everything works perfectly, with the server/client, when everything is going as inteded. However, if people attempt to open connections, and not send any messages, I'm not sure it will be able to keep up.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I will look into ReST, thanks.